# mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements

Tags: sql-server

I have seen a few posts here about this problem but none seem to apply to my code. Here is the code that I have. Can anyone give me some advice about what I may be doing wrong. As far as I can see I do a COMMIT or ROLLBACK each time. However I always get the error below. Please note I edited the code and removed things after the inserts to make it small so it fits on the page.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE post_user_test
    @ErrorMessage nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT,
    @RC     INT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY   
        DECLARE @SEQ INT;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SELECT @SEQ = Isnull(@SEQ,0)
        INSERT INTO dbo.UserTest .....
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50001,'xxx',1  
        SET @UserTestId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        INSERT INTO dbo.UserTestQuestion .....
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50002,'xxx',1
        SET @RC = 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        RETURN 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @RC = 1
        SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN
    END CATCH 
END
```

Here's the error message I am getting:

> Unexpected error:{"message":"Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates
>   a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements.

Comment: Perhaps your SPROC is being called from within another transaction, e.g. wrapped within another `BEGIN TRAN`, or from an `SqlTransaction` or a `TransactionScope`. If this is the case, you'll need to cater for the existing transaction and include the use of [Save Points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms188378.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code.. added `;` as well as checked for rollback count in the catch block.. and removed `RETURN` statements

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE post_user_test
     @ErrorMessage nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT,
     @RC     INT OUTPUT

 AS
 BEGIN
     BEGIN TRY   
         DECLARE @SEQ INT;
         BEGIN TRANSACTION;
         SELECT @SEQ = Isnull(@SEQ,0);
         INSERT INTO dbo.UserTest .....;
         IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50001,'xxx',1  
         SET @UserTestId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
         INSERT INTO dbo.UserTestQuestion .....;
         IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50002,'xxx',1
         SET @RC = 0;
         COMMIT TRANSACTION;
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
         SET @RC = 1;
         SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
     END CATCH 
 END;
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I tried your suggestions but unfortunately I still get the same error :-(

Comment: Could you try removing the `THROW` statements and see if it works.. if the rowcount != 1 I think the insert would fail anyways and should get caught in the catch block

Comment: I did as you suggested and it worked. But I am wondering how I can put a throw in and have it still work. The insert statements are actually INSERT INTO SELECT .. so they could have a rowcount of 1 or 99.  Is there a way that I could pick up != 1 and still send that to a catch?

Comment: Could you not check the `@@ROWCOUNT` in the `CATCH` block and invoke your `THROW` there after rolling back the transaction?